# How to change the style of an UIView when it's tapped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I'm making different UIView's tappable (they're not inheriting from UIControl) using the following code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userTappedOnLink:)];
[labelView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[labelView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

but I'd also like to change the style when they're highlighted. How do I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/mta452/UIView-TouchHighlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding an UIControl as a subview in the UIView. The UIControl is the same size has a transparent background that changes when it's highlighted. Works like a charm!

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Did you have to subclass UIControl? Any chance you could post your full code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Attach UILongPressGestureRecognizer instead of UITapGestureRecognizer to parent view and set it's properties to your liking. The way to track and respond to selection is to implement  userTappedOnLink method in appropriate way. This method will be called lots of times in short amount of time when gesture recognizer is activated and you know what's happening by tracking recognizer states.

Implement UIView subclass and create methods, like select and deselect, and customize view properties for each. Then it's only matter of finding which UIView subclass to select or deselect and that's easily done with UIGestureRecognizer method returning point in parent view and iterating trough it's subviews while checking if touch point is inside of particular subview frame.

```
- (IBAction)userTappedOnLink:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{

    switch (sender.state) 
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
{

        CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:self.parentView];
        for (UIView *subView in [self.parentView subViews) 
        {
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(subView.frame, tapPoint))
            {
                self.activeSubView = self.subview;
                            break;
            }
        }
                [self.activeSubView select];

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:[self.activeSubView doNothing];; break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:[self.activeSubView deSelect]; self.activeSubView = nil; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't get it to work... you get UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded even if the tap is outside of the target  so I don't know if I should open the link or not.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I did something very similar in the end!

Comment: I just realized that when you tap something using this method you can't scroll the view anymore while tapping... any idea how to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of handling events in iOS. The first one is to use UIView subclassing and override the methods that are inherited by UIView from [UIResponder class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a) (i.e. touchesBegan:withEvent, touchesMoved:withEvent, touchesEnded:withEvent, touchesCancelled:withEvent).

The second way is to create new instance of gesture recognizer class and add it to your UIView object (just like you did) and then create a handler.

```
- (IBAction)userTappedOnLink:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    // Changing view properties.
}
```

In both cases you can change the UIView properties. You can find some useful information in ["Event handling guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1) by Apple. There is a lot of reading but you can have a look only at the "related sample code" ([Touches](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435) and [SimpleGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460)).

The way you change the style properties of the interface elements in your application depends on what those properties are. Sometimes they can be animated sometimes they're not. Usually the code that changes view properties is placed inside the touchesBegin function or gesture recognizer handler. [MoveMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007315) sample code shows how to change  views properties and animate them. In the Gesture recognizers [chapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) of the "Event handling guide" frame properties are changed.

Comment: I'm trying to change the style on the view when it's selected/highlighted, i.e. when you tap it but didn't yet let go.. I couldn't find an easy way to detect that.

Comment: In this case I would try to implement touchesBegin (but it requires subclassing). Why don't you use subclassing by the way? You can still add the gesture recognizers to the subclassed views just the same way you do with regular UIView. Only the class name changes and a couple of files are added to your project. Im not sure but as an alternative to subclassing, you can also try to set some object (view controller for example) as a delegate for gesture recognizer and implement touchesBegin but I'm not quite sure if it will work properly.

Comment: I can use subclassing, but I was looking for a more generic solution as I'd like to do this for several views.

Answer (score 0):

well, I have not tested it, just a suggestion, please handle touchesbegin for this view,and call `[labelView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];` function.
maybe you should use another function, `- (void)removeGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer .`