# How do you detect touches in specific UIView when sliding finger across mutiple UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, gestures

The scenario I am trying to solve is I have several UIViews as subviews of a master UIView. What I want to be able to do is highlight a views rect by lets say changing its border as a finger slides across the view..similar to what happens when you move/drag your mouse cursor over a hypertext link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006851/how-to-change-the-style-of-an-uiview-when-its-tapped - Replace UITapGestureRecognizer with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Comment: Thanks @TheBlack this would work in the same way as using touchesMoved I guess, my problem seems to be detecting which subview is under the finger while a gesture is in progress on the parent view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the location of the touch inside your `touchesMoved:` method, then ask the master UIView which view was touched:

```
- (void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *subview = [masterView hitTest:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:masterView] withEvent:nil];
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks highlycaffeinated, I have tried this however the touchesMoved on the parent UIView gets the touches ok but if you start the touch in this view and slide across a child view the child UIView does not appear to receive touchesbegan or touchesmoved events as this parent view gets everything.

Comment: Right, and once you have the location of the touch in the parent view, you can ask the parent view which of its subviews that point corresponds to using the hitTest method. If that's not working, can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: @highlycaffeinated `code` - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: touch.view];
  
    AbstractAnnotation *subview = (AbstractAnnotation *)[self hitTest:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self] withEvent:nil];
    
    if ([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(AnnotationSelected)]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"moved over subview");
        [subview AnnotationSelected];
    };
    
    NSLog(@"AnnotationComponent touchesBegan x=%f y=%f", location.x, location.y);
}

Comment: You get location as a CGPoint relative to touch.view, but then you call hitTest with locationInView self.  This will work if self == touch.view, but not if they are different views.

Comment: Also, if self is your master view, you should use self in your call to [touch locationInView:].

Comment: will try that and get back to you, thanks for your help so far ;-)

Comment: still no luck! will post the updated code to see if that makes any sense.

Comment: Would like to see your code. In a test project I added the following :
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 NSLog(@"touches moved - view: %@", [self.view hitTest:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view] withEvent:event]);
}
console shows each view I drag across in turn:
2011-05-22 10:17:45.145 Sandbox[46687:207] touches moved - view: <UIView: 0x5f4dbe0; frame = (0 20; 320 460);
2011-05-22 10:17:45.161 Sandbox[46687:207] touches moved - view: <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x5f4d810; frame = (0 0; 280 38);

Comment: I have managed to get this mechanism working @highlycaffeinated with one of my basic UIView subclasses...so I think my problem is with one of my AbstractAnnotation subclasses which contains a subview itself. I will investigate and post back when sorted..thanks for all your help.

Comment: @highlycaffeinated yep that was it, cracked it..the subview I was interested in was behind a UIImageView ;-) thanks for all your help.