# How can I remove a UIView by the user tapping or swiping anywhere else?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, touches

I've created a mini pop-up menu for the iPhone in a `UIView`, and I'd like the user to be able to dismiss the view if they do anything other than select one of the options. So, if a user taps/swipes/pinches any other element on the screen, the pop-up view should disappear.

However, I don't want to detect a gesture that will stop something else from happening... For example, there is a `UITableView` underneath and if I swipe up or down on it, I want it to move as expected *as well as* dismissing the mini pop-up view.

Should I use multiple gesture recognizers, or should I use touchesBegan, or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078001/how-do-you-detect-touches-in-specific-uiview-when-sliding-finger-across-mutiple

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your `UIViewController`

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.view!=yourView && yourView) {
        [yourView removeFromSuperview];
        yourView=nil;
    }

}
```

EDIT: changes made to detect touch and remove only if view exists

EDIT2:  Well you could add the following to your `UIButtons/UITableView` methods

```
 if (yourView) {
     [yourView removeFromSuperview];
     yourView=nil;
    }
```

or add `touchesBegan:withEvent:` as a touchDown event to your buttons.

Both annoying to do but can't see another way to do it as the `touchesBegan` method doesn't get called with interactive elements.

EDIT3:  Right scrap that, think i've nailed it

in your interface add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
```

then in your `viewDidLoad` add this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapMethod)];
tapped.delegate=self;
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

then in your viewController add these 2 methods

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
if (touch.view!=yourView && yourView) {
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}

-(void)tapMethod {
[yourView removeFromSuperview];
yourView=nil;
}
```

Comment: So would I have to attach the touchesBegan method to the view controller? If so, I guess I'd need to check the elements under the touch somehow?

Comment: this is what he already does with `if (touch.view!=yourView)` you can then safely remove yourView in the if braces.

touch contains the location of the touch. he then asks if it is within the view, and if not you can remove it =)

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately this only seems to work on areas of the view controller that have no user interaction... on areas where I have `UIButton`s and a `UITableView`, the `touchesBegan:` message doesn't appear to be getting through.